# pgAdmin4: Cant find postgreSQL.conf, folder c:/Program Files/PostgreSQL doesnt exist

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Windows 10
PGadmin 4
It works tooooo slow even if I try "select * from tbl" with 3 rows (30sec+). Ive found this: "change listen_addresses = '127.0.0.1,::1' in postgreSQL.conf" but I cant find it :( no folder in ProgramFiles.

*.exe is in "C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4" but there is no conf.
I tried SHOW config_file and got /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata/postgresql.conf but I have no idea where it is :)
Tried fo use the search - no success

Comment: I cannot read anything out of this except general unhappiness. `postgresql.conf` is on the database server, not in pgAdmin. Why do you need it?